# Close windows with middle click in preview pane (SUPER-W)

Tags: 11.04, unity, compiz

I am using 11.04 with Unity. When I press SUPER-W, the previews of open windows align on the screen. If I click one of them, it attains focus.

I used to have this enabled as a Compiz plugin in ccsm (not sure which one), but back then middle clicking on a window preview would close that window. Very useful.

How can I have middle-clicking close the preview I middle clicked in the SUPER-W pane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

enable plugin scale addons ( in section utility ). There you can set with which mouse button you can close, pull etc...

Comment: For those of you who do this: Unity trips out at first, but if you log out then in, it's fixed.